# quel est le mot français pour "case" dans le contexte des mathématiques ou de la programmation informatique ?

Tags: informatique, mathématiques, typographie, technologie

Examples of American usage of the word "case" is shown below:

Définir σ = "BLEU".

plus précisément, définir **σ** comme une fonction de ℕ* sur l'ensemble des caractères unicode  tel que **σ** est nulle pour n suffisamment grand:

il existe un m dans ℕ tel que pour tout m >= n, σ(m) = 0

ADDITIONALLY,

```
σ(n) =
\begin{cases}
"B",  & \text{if } $n = 1$ \\
"L", & \text{if } $n = 2$ \\
"E", & \text{if } $n = 3$ \\
"U", & \text{if } $n = 4$ \\
NULL, & \text{if } $n >= 5$ \\
\end{cases}
```

Si vous avez le temps, veuillez appuyer sur le bouton d'édition pour corriger mon horrible français. Sinon, retournez à la liste des questions sans réponses pour un contenu de meilleure qualité.

[non comestible] ⟶ [(cas 1) ou (cas 2) ou (cas 3)]

[(pas le cas 1) ou (pas le cas 2) ou (pas le cas 3)] implique [comestible]

Nous définissons les aliments non comestibles comme suit :

> la nourriture n'est pas comestible dans un des trois cas

> (Case 1 of 3) la nourriture vous casse les dents par interaction ***physique*** si la nourriture ne contient pas plus de 0,01 % de gravier en masse lorsque le gravier n'a pas plus de 1/100 de millimètre de diamètre.
>
> (Case 2 of 3) le poids de l'aliment contient plus de 0,01 % de contaminants ***chimiques***, tels que le plomb, le cyanure ou la strichnine.
>
> (Case 3 of 3) le poids de l'aliment contient des agents ***biologiques*** de type loup ou de la vie microscopique à plus de 0,01%. il existe des Animaux plus petits que des grains de poussière. les virus, les bactéries et les amibes sont comme les cerfs et les loups. Les bactéries ressemblant à des loups vous causent du tort. les bactéries ressemblant à des cerfs ne vous font pas de mal.

La nourriture que vous avez laissée tomber sur le sol contient moins de 0,01 % de contaminants ***physiques*** tels que du gravier ou du verre brisé.

La nourriture que vous avez laissée tomber sur le sol contient moins de 0,01 % de contaminants ***chimiques***. il ne contient ni plomb, ni cyanure, ni toxine chimique.

Il n'y a que les animaux et les plantes plus petits ***biologiques*** que les bactéries à combattre.

In the programming language named **LaTeX** there exists a command based `case`.

Comment: Dans d'autres langages de programmation, ce type de structure de code est souvent appelé "switch". Je ne vois pas de traduction française en dehors de "branchement/traitement conditionnel", mais ce terme recouvre aussi les "if.. then... else ...".

Comment: Your command, as it is written , will give you an error warning. The environment "cases" is a math command (amsmath), you need the dollar signs. ($\begin{cases} … \end{cases}$).

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a pas de mot particulier. La commande « cases » est une commande qui permet un alignement de style mathématique, en fait c'est une commande du même type que « align ». On peut l'utiliser pour une liste de plusieurs cas en tant que possibilités correspondant à une chose selon une condition, ou on peut l'utiliser pour une simple énumération ; « cas » peut être utilisé mais c'est un mot que l'on associe à un certain type de liste, comme par exemple la liste des intervalles sur lesquels est définie une fonction. Un terme général serait « liste ».  Cependant, dans le Latex, il existe déjà les environnements de liste. « Listage » est aussi un terme de l'informatique et donc il est préférable de ne pas l'utiliser. « Éléments » est assez général, mais les accents ne sont pas acceptés dans les commandes Latex, ce qui revient à écrire « elements » et le résultat est quelque chose d'ambigu, de l'anglais en fait. Il y a cependant le terme « *individus* » en tant que terme général, si on ne veut pas se restreindre au cas des énumérations de conditions correspondant à une chose mathématique donnée.